# Flattening out the array of json in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I am getting started with javascript. Struggling with flattening out a javascript object.

```
[
   {
      "timestamp":"2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "result":[
         {
            "MarketShare":89905.0,
            "Territory":"PHILADELPHIA PA"
         },
         {
            "MarketShare":82991.0,
            "Territory":"SEATTLE WA"
         },

      ]
   },
   {
      "timestamp":"2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "result":[
         {
            "MarketShare":73662.0,
            "Territory":"PHILADELPHIA PA"
         },
         {
            "MarketShare":67059.0,
            "Territory":"SEATTLE WA"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "timestamp":"2019-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "result":[
         {
            "MarketShare":72898.0,
            "Territory":"PHILADELPHIA PA"
         },
         {
            "MarketShare":68013.0,
            "Territory":"SEATTLE WA"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "timestamp":"2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "result":[
         {
            "MarketShare":74607.0,
            "Territory":"PHILADELPHIA PA"
         },
         {
            "MarketShare":66769.0,
            "Territory":"SEATTLE WA"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "timestamp":"2019-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "result":[
         {
            "MarketShare":93932.0,
            "Territory":"PHILADELPHIA PA"
         },
         {
            "MarketShare":86514.0,
            "Territory":"SEATTLE WA"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

The expected output format is :

```
[
{"timestamp":"2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","MarketShare":89905.0,"Territory":"PHILADELPHIA PA"},
{"timestamp":"2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","MarketShare":82991.0,"Territory":"SEATTLE WA"},
{"timestamp":"2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z","MarketShare":73662.0,"Territory":"PHILADELPHIA PA"},
{"timestamp":"2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z","MarketShare":67059.0,"Territory":"SEATTLE WA"},
{"timestamp":"2019-03-01T00:00:00.000Z","MarketShare":72898.0,"Territory":"PHILADELPHIA PA"},
{"timestamp":"2019-03-01T00:00:00.000Z","MarketShare":68013.0,"Territory":"SEATTLE WA"},
{"timestamp":"2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z","MarketShare":74607.0,"Territory":"PHILADELPHIA PA"},
{"timestamp":"2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z","MarketShare":66769.0,"Territory":"SEATTLE WA"},
{"timestamp":"2019-05-01T00:00:00.000Z","MarketShare":93932.0,"Territory":"PHILADELPHIA PA"},
{"timestamp":"2019-05-01T00:00:00.000Z","MarketShare":86514.0,"Territory":"SEATTLE WA"}
]
```

Trying to build a generic function which can flatten any number of key-value pair present in the result array. A simple explanation of how to manipulate json objects in javascripts would be very helpful

Comment: Could you share the code you've gotten so far in your attempt to do this and point out where its failing?

Answer (score 3):

You can try that (assuming yourArray contains your array):

```
let out = [];

for( obj of yourArray  ) {
  for( res of obj.result ) {
    out.push({ ...res, timestamp:obj.timestamp })
  }
}

console.log(out);
```